# Is there any way to merge all galleries on a page?

Tags: featherlight.js

Is there any way to merge all galleries on a page? That is, if I have more than one section with `data-featherlight-gallery`, is there any way that the previous/next actions, when looking at the large version of an image, can cycle through all the images referenced in the page, rather than just the ones in that gallery?

I’m using this on a blog, and I break up the images into groups, but I want the reader to be able to cycle through the entire set of images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the binding manually, or else have a very high level `data-featherlight-gallery` (on the `body` if need be)...

Comment: Forgive me, I barely understand Javascript. Can you give me an example of how to do the binding manually? I can envision a situation where I want some, but not all images, in the gallery.

Ideally, I could put something like `data-featherlight-gallery="<some gallery ID>"` on all the images I want to belong to a particular gallery, and featherlight would automatically figure it out.